# route changes but outlet not in first time

Tags: angular, routes

i have a router outlet in my component to render inner tabs, it works fine but when i want to rout from one of tabs to other page with different out let it changes the route but not load the new page data for the first time, and when i refresh it works fine:

[image]

this is my search component:

```
<div class="bg-white">
    <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center">
        <ul class="nav secondary-nav alternate search-tab">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a  class="nav-link"
                    routerLinkActive="active"
                    routerLink="/search/by-voucher-code"
                    jhiTranslate="search.searchByVoucherCode.title">
                    Search By Voucher Code
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a  class="nav-link"
                    routerLinkActive="active"
                    routerLink="/search/by-national-identifier"
                    jhiTranslate="search.searchByNationalIdentifier.title">
                    Search By National Identifier
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a  class="nav-link"
                    routerLinkActive="active"
                    routerLink="/search/by-pass-number"
                    jhiTranslate="search.searchByPassNumber.title">
                    Search By Pass Number
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content" class="py-5 my-5 search-container">
    <div class="container my-5 py-5">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

my route config:

```
export const SEARCH_ROUTE: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'search',
        component: SearchComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthenticatedStateGuardResolverService, SelectedAgentGuardAndResolverService],
        data: {
            authorities: [],
            pageTitle: 'search.title'
        },
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                pathMatch: 'full',
                redirectTo: '/search/by-voucher-code'
            },
            {
                path: 'by-voucher-code',
                component: SearchByVoucherCodeComponent,
                data: {
                    authorities: [],
                    pageTitle: 'search.searchByVoucherCode.title'
                }
            },
            {
                path: 'by-national-identifier',
                component: SearchByNationalIdentifierComponent,
                data: {
                    authorities: [],
                    pageTitle: 'search.searchByNationalIdentifier.title'
                }
            },
            {
                path: 'by-pass-number',
                component: SearchByPassNumberComponent,
                data: {
                    authorities: [],
                    pageTitle: 'search.searchByPassNumber.title'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: 'receipt',
        component: ReceiptComponent,
        canActivate: [SelectedAgentGuardAndResolverService, ReceiptDataByVoucherResolverService],
        data: {
            authorities: [],
            pageTitle: 'receipt.title'
        },
        resolve: {
            receiptData: ReceiptDataByVoucherResolverService
        }
    }
];
```

by clicking search button it should navigate to receipt page but it doesn't work for the first time:

[image]
current url: **http://localhost:9060/receipt**

Comment: ASAK @Fatema Fazli could you please check any errors in the console when the search page navigates for the first time?Thanks

Comment: @77792 there is no error and i tried this without any guard and resolver but same result.

Comment: just a workaround to check what the problem you may add break points in your SearchByVoucherCodeComponent you will help you plot the problem